# Worklight error when sending push notification

Tags: push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

I am trying to use Worklight push notification to send push for a iOS+Android Application.

I created the submitNotification function in my adapter, and when I invoke it, it says that the push was sent successfully, but in reality, I have no push received in my device.

When I see the logs I can read:

```
Couldn't connect to APNS server
java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:432)
java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:570)
com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.<init>(SSLSocketImpl.java:371)
com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(SSLSocketFactoryImpl.java:71)
com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsConnectionImpl.socket(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:133)
com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsConnectionImpl.sendMessage(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:160)
com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsServiceImpl.push(ApnsServiceImpl.java:46)
com.notnoop.apns.internal.AbstractApnsService.push(AbstractApnsService.java:52)
com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsServiceImpl.push(ApnsServiceImpl.java:36)
com.worklight.integration.notification.apns.ApplicationConnection.sendNotification(ApplicationConnection.java:84)
com.worklight.integration.notification.apns.APNSMediator.sendNotification(APNSMediator.java:85)
com.worklight.integration.notification.Mediator$4.run(Mediator.java:174)
java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

and

```
Couldn't send message com.notnoop.apns.EnhancedApnsNotification@96eee2c0                                  com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsConnectionImpl.socket(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:146)
com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsConnectionImpl.sendMessage(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:160)
com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsServiceImpl.push(ApnsServiceImpl.java:46)
com.notnoop.apns.internal.AbstractApnsService.push(AbstractApnsService.java:52)
com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsServiceImpl.push(ApnsServiceImpl.java:36)
com.worklight.integration.notification.apns.ApplicationConnection.sendNotification(ApplicationConnection.java:84)
com.worklight.integration.notification.apns.APNSMediator.sendNotification(APNSMediator.java:85)
com.worklight.integration.notification.Mediator$4.run(Mediator.java:174)
java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

then

```
 Failed to send message com.notnoop.apns.EnhancedApnsNotification@96eee2c0... trying again
```

My submitNotification function :

```
function submitNotification(userId, notificationText) {
    var userSubscription = WL.Server.getUserNotificationSubscription(
            'myAdapter.MyPushEventSource', userId);

    if (userSubscription == null) {
        return {
            result : "No subscription found for user :: " + userId
        };
    }

    WL.Logger.debug("submitNotification >> userId :: " + userId + ", text :: "
            + notificationText);

    WL.Server.notifyAllDevices(userSubscription, {
        badge : 1,
        activateButtonLabel : "Open",
        alert : notificationText
    });

    return {
        result : "Notification sent to user :: " + userId
    };
}
```

Is there something wrong with my code? or with my Network ?

Comment: This was a network issue

Comment: Could you also write this as an Answer below and mark is later is Answered? Thanks.

Comment: Yes I can, but I should wait some hours : I have this stackoverflow message "Users with less than 10 reputation can't answer their own question for 8 hours after asking. You can answer in x hours. Until then please use comments, or edit your question instead."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was finally a network issue.

We changed our Firewall configuration to allow access to Google and Apple push servers.
For Apple Servers, you can find more details at this address : http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2265/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010376-CH1-TNTAG41

> the entire 17.0.0.0/8 address block is assigned to Apple, so you can
>   specify that range in your firewall rules.