# Worklight Push exception: SocketException: Connection closed by remote host

Tags: sockets, exception, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, ibm-mobilefirst

I did all steps of Push and now when calling Push its giving following exception.

I am calling IBM's sample Push code. I can see in the DB that device ID, Token, user ID are there as user has successfully subscribed for Push.

```
[4/10/13 18:27:24:647 AST] 00000044 JavaScriptInt I com.worklight.integration.js.JavaScriptIntegrationLibraryImplementation log Push Called -----> userId:aahad notificationText:ThisismyPushMessage
[4/10/13 18:27:24:663 AST] 00000044 JavaScriptInt I com.worklight.integration.js.JavaScriptIntegrationLibraryImplementation log submitNotification >> userId :: aahad, text :: ThisismyPushMessage
[4/10/13 18:27:24:679 AST] 00000045 ApnsConnectio W com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsConnectionImpl sendMessage Failed to send message com.notnoop.apns.EnhancedApnsNotification@6acb1af9... trying again
                                 java.net.SocketException: Connection closed by remote host
    at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.k(SSLSocketImpl.java:165)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.k.write(k.java:30)
    at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:69)
    at com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsConnectionImpl.sendMessage(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:161)
    at com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsServiceImpl.push(ApnsServiceImpl.java:46)
    at com.notnoop.apns.internal.AbstractApnsService.push(AbstractApnsService.java:52)
    at com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsServiceImpl.push(ApnsServiceImpl.java:36)
    at com.worklight.integration.notification.apns.ApplicationConnection.sendNotification(ApplicationConnection.java:84)
    at com.worklight.integration.notification.apns.APNSMediator.sendNotification(APNSMediator.java:85)
    at com.worklight.integration.notification.Mediator$4.run(Mediator.java:174)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:452)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:897)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:919)
```

From WL server machine I can telnet Apple servers.

Is there any other thing that I have to check on my network? as my client has very strict securities.

This is Push adapter function code I am using.

```
function testNotification(userId ,notificationText){
    WL.Logger.debug("Push Called -----> userId:" + userId + " notificationText:"+notificationText);
    var userSubscription = 
        WL.Server.getUserNotificationSubscription('PushAdapter.PushEventSource', userId);

    if (userSubscription==null){
        return { result: "No subscription found for user :: " + userId };
    }

    WL.Logger.debug("submitNotification >> userId :: " + userId + ", text :: " + notificationText);

    WL.Server.notifyAllDevices(userSubscription, {
        badge: 1,
        sound: "sound.mp3",
        activateButtonLabel: "ClickMe",
        alert: notificationText,
        payload: {
            foo : 'bar'
        }
    });

    return { result: "Notification sent to user :: " + userId };
}
```

**I have narrowed down this problem.**

I did Push demo on my local machine (windows 7 lenovo laptop)  WL Consumer studio using jetty and it worked fine. I received notifications.

I figured out that i am doing one mistake that is I am using Development APNS certificate with distribution profile....that means WL server would be sending request to wrong  Apple server.

I tried above thing on my laptop to test Push demo, plus I also stopped my firewall & Norton antivirus on my personal laptop, in this way Push worked fine.

Now today at client end, I re-generated another APNS certificate that is Production APNS and using distribution profile I am trying to achieve this. This time I am receiving different exception.

```
[4/11/13 12:36:32:566 AST] 00000046 JavaScriptInt I com.worklight.integration.js.JavaScriptIntegrationLibraryImplementation log Push Called -----> userId:aahad notificationText:This is my First Push Message
[4/11/13 12:36:32:566 AST] 00000046 JavaScriptInt I com.worklight.integration.js.JavaScriptIntegrationLibraryImplementation log submitNotification >> userId :: aahad, text :: This is my First Push Message
[4/11/13 12:36:32:676 AST] 0000003b webcontainer  E com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.internal.WebContainer handleRequest SRVE0255E: A WebGroup/Virtual Host to handle /favicon.ico has not been defined.
[4/11/13 12:36:58:066 AST] 00000045 ApnsConnectio E com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsConnectionImpl socket Couldn't connect to APNS server
                                 java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:381)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:243)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:230)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:377)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:539)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:284)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.<init>(SSLSocketImpl.java:712)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(SSLSocketFactoryImpl.java:15)
    at com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsConnectionImpl.socket(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:133)
    at com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsConnectionImpl.sendMessage(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:160)
    at com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsServiceImpl.push(ApnsServiceImpl.java:46)
    at com.notnoop.apns.internal.AbstractApnsService.push(AbstractApnsService.java:52)
    at com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsServiceImpl.push(ApnsServiceImpl.java:36)
    at com.worklight.integration.notification.apns.ApplicationConnection.sendNotification(ApplicationConnection.java:84)
    at com.worklight.integration.notification.apns.APNSMediator.sendNotification(APNSMediator.java:85)
    at com.worklight.integration.notification.Mediator$4.run(Mediator.java:174)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:452)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:897)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:919)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:772)

[4/11/13 12:36:58:066 AST] 00000045 ApnsConnectio W com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsConnectionImpl sendMessage Failed to send message com.notnoop.apns.EnhancedApnsNotification@4fc0c1a1... trying again
                                 com.notnoop.exceptions.NetworkIOException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsConnectionImpl.socket(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:146)
    at com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsConnectionImpl.sendMessage(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:160)
    at com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsServiceImpl.push(ApnsServiceImpl.java:46)
    at com.notnoop.apns.internal.AbstractApnsService.push(AbstractApnsService.java:52)
    at com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsServiceImpl.push(ApnsServiceImpl.java:36)
    at com.worklight.integration.notification.apns.ApplicationConnection.sendNotification(ApplicationConnection.java:84)
    at com.worklight.integration.notification.apns.APNSMediator.sendNotification(APNSMediator.java:85)
    at com.worklight.integration.notification.Mediator$4.run(Mediator.java:174)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:452)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:314)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:897)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:919)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:772)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:381)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:243)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:230)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:377)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:539)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:284)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketImpl.<init>(SSLSocketImpl.java:712)
    at com.ibm.jsse2.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(SSLSocketFactoryImpl.java:15)
    at com.notnoop.apns.internal.ApnsConnectionImpl.socket(ApnsConnectionImpl.java:133)
    ... 13 more
```

Now here are two things we have to understand, help in this please.

**(1)** By looking at Logs , does it still means there is network blockage somewhere at client side?

**(2)** I am seeing one difference in Keychain when it is showing both Development APNS & Production APNS certificates. Both are using same private key. The development apns certificate shows App ID "us.com.abc.myApp" as Post-fix to it.....While the Production apns certificate is NOT showing it. ........ **Is this fine? Or will it cause some problem** ?....... I tried re-generating Production APNS certificates three times but each time it is showing same number and not APP ID as Post-fix.

**Thanks**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question #1: See this Stackoverflow question about APNS and network access: [Worklight error when sending push notification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15429116/worklight-error-when-sending-push-notification)

From an [Apple technote:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2265/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010376-CH1-TNTAG41)

> the entire 17.0.0.0/8 address block is assigned to Apple, so you can
>   specify that range in your firewall rules.

Question #2: familiarize yourself with the topic of APNS, [see this blog post](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/understanding-and-setting-up-push-notifications-in-development-evnironment?lang=en).

Comment: I have read it. I did all steps correctly that's why at my local laptop Push works fine. Only facing problem at client end that is very much secure network. The second question, the above shared link too shows Development Push example that is fine to me. But I am NOT seeing App Id in Production APNS certificate in keyChain.  for example, if Development APNS cert: in KeyChain shows like this **AXD2GH44D.com.ba.myApp** then Production is showing **AXD2GH44D.AXD2GH44D** .... I am thinking that why both have differences?

Comment: It was a network level issue, my network team opened port on external firewall and it worked perfectly.